# Simple left join?

Tags: join, left-join, cross-reference

I have 3 tables that contain several transactions for the last 5 years for each building.  The tables are at the building level and have a unique building_code for each building that also serves as a key.

The tables are Expense, Revenue, and balance sheet.  These tables also are linked to additional foreign keys fund_code, function_code, object_code, receipt_code.  It is a many to many relationship between the three.  Examples of the table design are below.

```
**Sample data**
Revenue_table:  
building_code - 1234, 1234, 1235   
function_code – 01, 02, 02  
fund_code - 001, 001, 002   
receipt_code – 11, 11, 12

Expense_table:  
building_code - 1234, 1234, 1334  
function_code – 01, 02, 02  
fund_code - 001, 001, 002   
object_code – 111, 111, 112  
receipt_code – 11, 11, 12

Balance_table:  
building_code - 1234, 1234, 1240  
fund_code - 001, 001, 005  
revenue – 2345.00, 456.00, 765.00

**Expected results:**  
building_code - 1234, 1234, 1240, 1235, 1334  
fund_code – 001, 001, 002, 005, 002  
function_code  - 01, 02, null, 02, 02  
receipt_code – 11, 11, null, null, 12  
object_code – 111, 111, null, null, 112  
revenue – 2345.00, 456.00, 765.00, null, null
```

I would like to merge all three tables together keeping all transactions while joining 
on transactions that match for each year between the three tables and keeping the transactions that don't for each year.

Comment: Not enough information about what you're trying to achieve. Post some sample data for the 3 tables, and the expected results.

Comment: begin by creating a SELECT for the main table... then add one table at a time with joins and verifying the results.

Comment: So are you suggesting a left join with all the tables to bring back all the results.